# Passing variable from controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can anyone help me understand this code and why it has an error appearing?

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: plain_pass
>
> Filename: views/editusers.php
>
> Line Number: 59
>
> Line 59:
>
> ```
> <td> 
> <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $plain_pass; ?>"> </td>
> ```

controllers/Cpages.php

```
 public function editusers() { 


    $user_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $data['users'] = $this->Mpages->call_point_users($user_id);

    foreach($users as $users_item) {            
        $encrypt_pass = $users_item['password'];            
        $plain_pass = $this->encrypt->decode($encrypt_pass);            
    }

    $this->load->view('editusers', $data, $plain_pass); 


}
```

views/editusers.php

```
                <div class="widget-box">
                    <div class="widget-title"><h5>Users</h5></div>
                    <div class="widget-content">

                    <?php echo form_open('cpages/editusersdb'); ?>                      
                    <table border="0" style="width: 100%; height: 90px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>NAME</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $users_item['username']; ?>"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>EMAIL</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $users_item['email']; ?>"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>PASSWORD</td>
                            <td><input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $plain_pass; ?>"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ROLE</td>
                            <td>
                            <select>
                            <optgroup>
                            <option value="Administrator">Administrator</option>
                            <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
                            </optgroup>
                            </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><input type="submit" class="edit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"></td>
                        </tr>                           
                    </table>            
                    </div>

                    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Don't forget when a answer has worked for you to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Put $plain_pass into your data array.

```
public function editusers() { 

    $user_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $data['users'] = $this->Mpages->call_point_users($user_id);

    foreach($users as $users_item) {            
        $encrypt_pass = $users_item['password'];            
        $plain_pass = $this->encrypt->decode($encrypt_pass);            
    }

    $data['plain_pass'] = $plain_pass; 

    $this->load->view('editusers', $data); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way I find

```
 $data['users'] = array();

 $results = $this->Mpages->call_point_users($user_id);

 if (isset($results)) {

 foreach ($results as $result) {
    $data['users'][] = array(
       'email' => $result['email'],
       'username' => $result['username'],
       'encrypt_pass' => $result['password'], 
       'plain_pass' => $this->encrypt->decode($result['encrypt_pass'])
    );
 }

 }

 $this->load->view('someview', $data);
```

> Don't have two types of pass words only have one. Also codeigniter
>   encrypt is not code still for passwords because it can be decrypted,
>   Instead use some like
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and for verify
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php varchar 255

View

```
<table>
<thead>

</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($users as $user) {?>
<tr>
<td>NAME</td>
<td><input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $user['username']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>EMAIL</td>
<td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $user['email']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>PASSWORD</td>
<td><input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $user['plain_pass']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
</tbody>
</table>
```